# no decode delegate for this image format `PNG'

Tags: wand

I'm writing a django/python application and I need to convert PDF files uploaded by the user to JPEGs (files are scans)

I'm trying to use wand, with an ImageMagick backend (on OSX) and
I keep getting the following error:

```
MissingDelegateError at /user_docs/upload/certificate/
no decode delegate for this image format `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/501
```

My current test code is as simple as:

```
with wandImage(filename='/Users/username/Pictures/telechargement.pdf') as img:
    img.format = 'jpeg'
    img.save(filename='/Users/username/Pictures/bzzz.jpeg')
```

Some information:

1. The file exists (I verify with `os.path.exists`)
2. I can convert the file from PDF to JPG on the command line using `convert`
3. I tried to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to include the ImageMagick lib directory
4. `identify -list configure | grep DELEGATES`  returns

`DELEGATES     bzlib fftw fontconfig freetype gs jpeg jng lcms2 lzma mpeg png tiff x11 xml zlib`

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, Found it! As always the key is RTFM:

> http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.4.0/guide/install.html#install-imagemagick-on-mac

I was missing the:

```
$ export MAGICK_HOME=/opt/local
```

Comment: The `MAGICK_HOME` environment variable is very important, see Anthony's [Hints & Tips](https://www.ict.griffith.edu.au/anthony/info/graphics/imagemagick.hints) document for additional info.

Comment: Both links given are dead. The doc for installing ImageMagick is now found at [https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php](https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php). I can't find Anthony's Hints and Tips.